# Custom query with more than one field on az ad sp list

Tags: azure, jmespath

Lets say I want to list `id` and `appId` from `az ad sp list`, how would one do that?

I get it working for only the `id` like this:

```bash
az ad sp list --query '[].id'
```

How can I extend this to `id` and `appId`?

I already tried

```bash
az ad sp list --query '[].id,[].appId'
az ad sp list --query '[].{id,appId}'
```

but both are invalid queries.

The output I am looking for should be something like

```json
[
  {"id": 1, "appId": 2},
  {"id": 3, "appId": 4}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a [multiselect](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#multiselect) in JMESPath, you can re-key your objects, so you will need to specify both a new key and an existing key. Of course, the new key can be the same as the existing one.

So, if you don't want to change the keys, your query should be:

```
[].{id: id, appId: appId}
```

And your Azure command:

```bash
az ad sp list --query '[].{id: id, appId: appId}'
```